# Installing Fedora 17 on vmware workstation 9

Tags: fedora, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install Fedora 17 on a remote machine through VMWare Workstation 9.0.0. I can start the machine in recovery mode just fine, but when the desktop loads I get a message saying:

**Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.**

(Really helpful, I know) Anyone else having this problem or know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and doing the following helped:

```
yum remove gnome-shell
yum install gnome-shell
yum update gnome*
```

After that everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using `yum remove dprintf` from the recovery console. After that it worked fine.